# Laravel - OutputStyle from jobs

Tags: laravel, symfony

I'm running into issues with allowing a Laravel job to interact with the console output.

At the moment I am passing in the OutputStyle from a Command to the Job constructor and assigning it.

I have seen the InteractsWithIO trait but if I use that by itself without assigning the OutputStyle from the command then it says it is null.

`Call to a member function title() on null`

I have also tried setting `$this->output` from the container using

`$this->output = resolve(OutputStyle::class);`

This fails with a

`Target [Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle].`

I've also ran into issues with PHPUnit tests that run through this job. The output from the class is displayed in the test output.

```
.......................Processing element 1 for "Section"
.......
```

What's the best way to handle outputting to the console within Laravel that also works with PHPUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the following code in a Service Provider works:

```
$this->app->bind('console.output', function () {
    return new OutputStyle(
        new StringInput(''),
        new StreamOutput(fopen('php://stdout', 'w'))
    );
});
```

I am then able to say, in my Job,

`$this->output = resolve('console.output');`

Which gives access to all the methods such as `title`, `section`, and `table`.